# Socket accept and multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have this issue I have no idea how to resolve and I'm at the brink of insanity. Programming, eh? :/

Anyway, I have a server which has a thread to send users all the info it needs to (which needs to run constantly) and another thread that awaits new server connections. My problem is once `socket.accept()` is called, the other thread doesn't execute.

So, to explain with code:

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {


  public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
      s=socket.accept();
    }
  }

class Thread2 extends Thread {

  public void run() {
    //do stuff
    System.out.println("spam");
  }
}

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
    t1.start();

    t1.Thread2 t2 = t1.new Thread2();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Assume all other required member variables are present, no compile errors and connection functionality works fine. Just 'Thread2' executes only once.

So my question is, how do I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a basic misunderstanding of threads. Let's see if we can clear that up.

Threads are simply another pipeline of execution. Think of them like *tasks* with a particular set of instructions. Once the task is done, the thread returns. Pretty simple idea, right?

In your example, `Thread1` has an endless loop, which makes sense that it *does* run infinitely and *does* accept clients indefinitely.

However, `Thread2` simply outputs some text and returns. There's nothing telling it to '*keep spinning*'.

Within your `main()`, even though `Thread2` is an inner class of `Thread1` (which is kind of bad form to begin with, might I add) it doesn't actually force the thread to keep running.

You'll probably want to add a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) to your server class that holds new sockets, and have `Thread2` loop and check for entries.

#### Further Reading

Firstly, take a look at the [`Thread` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). Its constructor takes a `Runnable`, so that's all you should be implementing when working with threads (i.e. `class Foo implements Runnable` and then `new Thread(new Foo())`).

If sockets are your fancy, perhaps some [further reading](http://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/042_serverarch.html) on socket-server architecture and even about protocol design would be something you'd benefit from.

Comment: Definitely had a misunderstanding, for some reason I convinced myself that threads repeat execution by nature :/ Thanks for the further reading, they're definitely of interest - I'll take a look at Queue too!

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions

- never extend a Thread as it's a good way to confuse yourself.  Never nest a Thread inside another Thread unless you really like confusion.
- if you want to run a thread for each socket, then create a new thread for each socket in the loop.

Try the following (Note: You can add IOException handling code)

```
class SocketAcceptor implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Socket s=socket.accept();
            SocketHandler sh = new SocketHandler(s);
            new Thread(sh).start();
        }
    }
}

class SocketHandler implements Runnable {
    final Socket s;
    SocketHandler(Socket s) { this.s = s; }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New connection " + s);
        s.close();
    }
```

}

A better solution would be to use a Thread pool. e.g. An ExecutorService, but I would get this working first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll change my implementation now before it gets out of hand :D Your answer made me realise, though, that I need a while loop or timer in my second thread otherwise it'll just execute the once - I'm a thread n00b :p

Comment: @Timmy as Peter correctly suggested - use an ExecutorService. A ScheduledExecutor service has some nice methods called "scheduleWithFixedDelay" and "schedulePeriodically" (or something like that). You can guess how much easier it's gonna be than using a timer.

Comment: An `ExecutorService` is mostly pointless when working with sockets since `Socket` operations block (normally). If anything his second thread that works with accepted sockets would be the only use case for an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @Qix if you want to recycle threads between socket connections, you want a pool.

Comment: @PeterLawrey depends on if his threads are single-shotting incoming connections or if he's processing/disposing of new connections in a single instance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 Though I think this discussion will soon descent to arguing whether it's better to have blocking thread per socket or non-blocking selector and workers... OPs question was answered, the details discussed now are far beyond it

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with anything here. Those are the preferred ways of handling something such as this. However, OP was ultimately misunderstanding threads, not sockets. Probably best to understand how threads work before trying to use higher-level constructs that abstract threads away ;)